# PHP time and difference

Tags: php, math, time, web-applications, server

I have a problem I've been thinking lately.

I'm trying to figure out on how to create a 2 minute countdown timer that'll constantly run even if there is no client running the PHP script. ( If the client connected to the page say it'd present 22 secs left and after that ends it'd reset back to 2 mins.);

I was thinking on creating a timestamp to register the time() and sort of calculating the difference between the actual time and the reformatted targeted time. However, with that I come up with another problem, how would the php script know when to reset it every 2 minutes?

I have no idea on how to solve this, maybe it has no solution but I'd love to see some ideas that could help me out!

Thanks!

```
<?php

/* A countdown timer of 2 minutes would be set from a specific time in anytime time I'd set ($timestamp), it should be able to reset everytime it reaches 0 or negative, it'd be synchronized to all users connected ( everyone would see the same )*/
  function generate_newtimestamp()
  {

  }
  $timestamp =  mktime(21, 43, 0, 4, 19, 2017); //(hour,minute,second,month,day,year) say this variable would start off 2 minutes ahead of current time at any time that was set, and this variable needs to self_update once 2 minutes pass (maybe server-sided...Any ideas?)  
  $today = time ();

// now I want to calculate the difference between the actual time itself and the 2 minutes target time I want it to run
if(!negativeTimestamp($timestamp, $today))
{
  $difference =($timestamp-$today);
  $minutes = floor($difference/60);
  $sec = ($difference/60 - $minutes) * 60;
  echo $minutes . "<br>";
  echo $sec;
}else{
  generate_newtimestamp();
}

function negativeTimestamp($time, $stamp)
{
  $difference =($stamp-$time);
  return ($stamp-$time<$difference) ? true : false;
}
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried, please show us some code?

Comment: Store the time the client loads the page in a `session`. On next load compare the time.

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Deeply sorry for not presentating code, I'll post it in a second!

Comment: Code has been added to my post, it would be kind to check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply perform some calculations on the current time to round it up to the nearest 2 full minutes. From there, I would then work out the difference between that rounded time and the current server time. Something like this:

```
$now = time();
$nextTwoMinute = ceil($now/120) * 120; //120 seconds = 2 minutes
print_r("Time Left: " . ($nextTwoMinute - $now));
```

This means your application will not need to run in the background, as it can rely on the time information from the server when a user requests the page. Obviously, if you needed to run a function every two minutes that need something more along the lines of a cron function.

Comment: that actually works xD! Thank you for your knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Storing timestamp somewhere and creating `cron job` running every few seconds. If current_time - timestamp >= 120 seconds: continue, if not:
 abort.

(it won't be very precise, but will work)

Comment: I appreciate your comment, however that'd be impossible for me since I cannot run cron job :[

Comment: Did you consider using a Web Cron service?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, mind explaining in detail what that is?

Comment: Those are services like: [link](https://cron-job.org/en/)
They just send request to url you specify in constant time interval. The same way as cron working on server.